# Date queries in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got a model with two datefields, start_date and end_date

I wish to query this model to get all model instances that range between two given dates. I also want models overlapping this range.

Those two given dates are the start date of a month and the end date.

I've tried doing something like:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(start_date__range=[start_range, end_range])|Q(end_date__range=[start_range, end_range]))
```

But this fails if the start_date and end_date lay more the one month apart.

Answer (score 0):

How does this fail ? Not returning objects where the range is superior to a month ?

I don't understand why your method won't work, but you can always try to use :

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(start_date__gt=start_range)|Q(end_date__lt=end_range))
```

This shall work as long as start_date is lower than end_date but this hould be handled in the form validation.

Another idea, but maybe it's not efficient in terms of database queries, would be to filter **out** objects that are **not** at all in the range. This seems more efficient from a logical point of view, but again, may not be in terms of data size and DB queries.

Comment: Also, I would'nt name the beginning of a range "start_range" but "range_start", "start_range" sounds like a... range.

Comment: The model has a start and end date, those two dates can be 3 months apart. I've got a month's start_date and end_date. I would like to get all models that have a start_date and/or end_date that lay within that given month. Your query doesn't do that.

Comment: Np, yes I would also like to receive the models that overlap the range too.

Comment: I fixed my answer, hope this is going to work for you. I'd really like to test it, but I don't have a Django environment ready for tests at this time.

Comment: I think this query holds the solutions        Project.objects.filter(Q(start_date__lte=start_range)|Q(start_date__range=[start_range, end_range]))\         .filter(Q(end_date__gte=end_range)|Q(end_date__range=[start_range, end_range])),

Answer (score -1):

```
Model.objects.filter(start_date__gt=start_range).filter(end_date__lt=end_range)
```

this is all you need

Comment: This won't work as he also wants objects overlapping the range.

Comment: i posted way before he commented your post dude :)

Comment: oh sorry didn't see that... in fact you even posted before I answered, but I missed it. sorry :/